# Flutter: how to traverse a Widget children?

Tags: flutter

Could anybody explain me how to traverse the children of a Widget Tree so that I can get the RenderObject of a specific child, based on its type?

The practical use case I have at the moment is that I need to get the dimensions of a Scaffold AppBar (since I have a generic Widget that needs to be positioned via a PopupMenu, just underneath the AppBar which might or not have a bottom).

As the AppBar does not expose its AppBarState, giving it a key is useless, I need to traverse the Scaffold children to find it back.

Many thanks

Comment: Assign a GlobalKey then you can access it directly without traversing using the key.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer, I did this and now, thanks to the _appBarKey.currentContext.findRenderObject(), I obtain its dimensions.

But, more generally, how is it feasible to traverse a Widget Tree to retrieve a child of a specific type, if we are not using any GlobalKey ?

Comment: There's a bunch of methods inside `context` to vist parents/children. But you shouldn't use them. That's anti-patern as your widget would have dependencies on the whole widget tree.

Answer (score 2):

What I do is something similar by fetching the RenderObject. To access the object, I'm casting the Widget that I intend to use. For example

```dart
RenderBox renderBox = key.currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
```

From this sample, I was able to access the object's properties by casting RenderBox.